# what is the meaning of Header & Body

Tags: php, html, api

I just couldn't understand what is nature of header and body when we request CRUD operations in our app!
what is exactly header means, and what does it need to be sent inside it?
Is there is relevance with HTML code?

Comment: Are you talking about header/body in HTTP requests or in HTML documents? And if you mean in HTML documents, do you mean `<head></head>` and `<body></body>`?

Comment: A very vage question. Please refrase it. Its not at all clear what you are struggeling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK!
In the HTML document header and body are:
**The  element** is a container for metadata (data about data) and is placed between the  tag and the  tag.
and the body is the main content of a web page that displays to the user.
[To read more...](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp)

But in PHP or server-side language:
**HTTP headers** are pieces of code central to the requests browsers send and the responses servers make in the process of rendering websites. Browser, server, and page information is transferred to deliver the content a user wants. These exchanges involve HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and other elements essential to the look and feel of the website.

Thanks!
Have a nice day.

Comment: Yeah, but i meant how actually do they work! in case of post or get request?